# Testing if ArcGIS Server is running correctly

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've recently installed ArcGIS Server 10.1, but I'm not sure if it installed correctly, or if the proper ports are open. Here is my reasoning and I may be off:

1. When publishing a new service(i.e newMap), the folder "arcgisserver\directories\arcgisoutput\newMap" remains empty, I'm assuming their should be a copy of the service in there now.
2. When trying to access the service through arcgis javascript api, I get a blank page. I copied and pasted the source code from the tab or window that pops up when you press "view" in the services thumbnail into a .html file. Then I replaced the url with the REST URL given to me under the services' capabilities options. I've also tried replacing localhost with my machine name and I still get a blank page.

   http://localhost/myorg/rest/services/MyMapService/MapServer

Can you provide me with some working test code?

I'm learning to use JavaScript API and server at the moment and I want to make sure its configured correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to check if your ArcGIS server is working, is to consume the services from it in ArcGIS desktop.

Please see this page for ways in which you can add service to your ArcMap: [Adding ArcGIS Server map services](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sp00000019000000.htm)

Coming to your issues:

1. No copy of a service is made in arcgisserver\directories\arcgisoutput\newMap. You need to check the arcgisinput folder instead.
2. There could be many reasons why you are not seeing the output in the 'View in ArcGIS JavaScript' link. First make sure that your services are running and consumable. Only after that tackle this problem.